# Geokettle insert in cascade, ETL normalization process

Tags: pentaho, etl, cascade, kettle, geokettle

I'm new to ETL process. At this moment I'm working with kettle more precisely with geokettle to make a ETL process. I'm building a transformation to insert data in a normalized structure on my database target from a descriptive table of a database source.

Please take into consideration the following example.

**Example:**

I'm trying to insert in cascade on my database a contact record. Notice that in the source database I have the following contact table:

[image: Database Source: Table Contacts]

I would like to transform into the following structure:

[image: Database Target: [Contact normalized tables]]

So the main idea is:

**step one**: Insert the phone in `CI_Telephone` table and get `t_id`.

**step two**: In parallel with the previous step insert `institutionAddress` and `country` on `CI_Address` and get `a_id`

**third step**: after that, i need to get those ids (`t_id` and `a_id`) to be inserted on `CI_Contact` (if not exist yet) and get the `c_id`

**fourth step**: Insert (if not already exists) on `CI_ResponsibleParty` the `instituionName` => `organizationName` and `name`=> `individualname`, and insert the correct foreign key (contactInfo) that references `CI_contact` table.

This was my idea about the ETL process:

[image: Geokettle approach]

**Question:**
How can you do a "cascade" insertion using geokettle or kettle? ( i dont know if this is the correct term) Does this transformation make sense to you?

I couldn't find any similar example to this case. Any suggestion about this issue would be great. Please, share your experience about ETL process and how to normalize a database from another that isn't normalized.

Answer (score 2):

These steps can be used for each step you specified.

> step one: insert the phone in CI_Telephone table and get t_id.

- Use `Dimension lookup/update` step. It will return the key created when you specified it in `Technical key` field.

> step two: In parallel with the previous step insert institutionAddress
>   and country on CI_Address and get a_id

- Use the same step parallelly to do the Address insertion and get the Id.

> third step: after that, i need to get those ids (t_id and a_id) to be
>   inserted on CI_Contact (if not exist yet) and get the c_id

- Use `Merge join` step to join the to streams using a key. Then use
  `Insert/Update` step to insert to CI_Contact if not exist.

> fourth step: Insert (if not already exists) on CI_ResponsibleParty the
>   instituionName => organizationName and name=> individualname, and
>   insert the correct foreign key (contactInfo) that references
>   CI_contact table.

- Use the same step as above to do the insertion.

**NB:** Since `Dimension lookup/update` and `Combination lookup/update` steps are there for Data Warehousing which is suited well for your requirement.